# Converting a char to a boolean - Java

Tags: java, char, boolean

Alright, so Im trying to work on some homework and I ran into this problem. How do I convert a char to a boolean? Im getting a char input from the keyboard first, a "Y" if the employee is opting for family insurance, and an "N" if they are not. Then I need to take that input and plug it into a method to calculate the total insurance. However, the parameter for the family insurance in the method is a boolean, so I need to somehow convert the char to a boolean, and set Y as true and N as false. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: And where is your issue here? That's just a simple `if`/`else` or ternary operator, nothing more. You don't need any "magic"

Comment: Sorry, im pretty new to java. The problem is that I need to make it so that if the user enters a char "Y" that the Y will be true and if they enter an "N", it will be false. I tried doing a if/else statement, like if cVar ('Y') then cVar=true and so on but that did not work.                                                                                                      
 The reason for all this is because a method I am having to use later in the program uses this variable (the Y or the N) as a parameter, but for the method to work, the parameter has to be a boolean.

Comment: When you have  tried something, then it is always a good idea to add that to the question, so the answer can explain to you why it didn't work and how what you should to to either fix your code or to achieve your goal with a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function. It takes as parameter the character variable and returns true if it's 'Y' otherwise it returns false.

```
public static boolean convertCharToBoolean(char input) {
    return Character.toLowerCase(input) == 'y' ? true : false;
}
```

You will also need to import the following library

```
import java.lang.*;
```

Comment: java.lang doesn't have to be imported, or as [the spec puts it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5): "Code in a compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang."

Comment: Also, ```someBooleanExpression ? true : false``` is a roundabout way to write ```someBooleanExpression```. The original means "if the value is true then the value is true else the value is false".

Comment: You are right and I know that but as I understood tophats it is new at programming and I chose to give the simplest solution that he is able to understand. Thank you for the comments though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the equality operator.

```
result = yourMethod(input == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a stepwise explanation.

Your requirements are, in pseudocode:

```
 if char is 'Y'
    then result is true
 if char is 'N'
    then result if false
```

As a specification, that's incomplete. What is the result if the input is neither 'Y' nor 'N'?   Let us make assumptions; anything that is not 'Y' is false.

```
  if char is 'Y'
      then result is true;
  else
      result is false;
```

You can code from that: (I assume we don't care about upper/lower case)

```
  boolean charToBool(char input) {
     if (input == 'Y' || input == 'y')
         return true;
     else
         return false;
   }
```

However, that's a bit wordy. The result of a conditional expression is itself a boolean that's either true or false, so we can reduce that to:

```
  boolean charToBool(char input) {
     return (input == 'Y' || input == 'y');
  }
```

Now you can just call that method with your input character.